# Is "the oft-cited XKCD scheme [...] no longer good advice"?

Tags: passwords

I was stumbling around and happened onto [this essay](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/03/choosing_secure_1.html) by Bruce Schneier claiming that the [XKCD password scheme](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase) was effectively dead.

> Modern password crackers combine different words from their dictionaries: [...]
>
> This is why the oft-cited XKCD scheme for generating passwords -- string together individual words like "correcthorsebatterystaple" -- is no longer good advice. The password crackers are on to this trick.
>
> The attacker will feed any personal information he has access to about the password creator into the password crackers. A good password cracker will test names and addresses from the address book, meaningful dates, and any other personal information it has. [...] if your program ever stored it in memory, this process will grab it.

His contention seems to be that because it's known that people might construct their passwords in such a way that it makes it amenable to attack, but it seems like the strength lies purely in the power of exponents. I assume he's alluding to people not choosing the words truly randomly, which perhaps isn't totally disingenuous, as I've rerolled a couple times to get something that isn't all adverbs and adjectives. However, I assume that lowering the entropy by a factor of 2-10 isn't really significant (if the word list is doubled to 4000, not that hard, the loss is more than recovered).

The other quip about "if your program ever stored it in memory" is a bit disconcerting though...aren't all passwords stored in memory at one time or another? That *seems* a bit overbroad; what is he actually referring to?

Comment: A discussion with 123 comments about this is on http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/1yxgqo/bruce_schneier_on_choosing_a_secure_password/

Comment: On mouseover, the image title reveals - _"To anyone who understands information theory and security and is in an infuriating argument with someone who does not (possibly involving mixed case), I sincerely apologize."_ This would help you :)

Comment: This TED talk has some interesting research on different password creation schemes, including the xkcd one: http://www.ted.com/talks/lorrie_faith_cranor_what_s_wrong_with_your_pa_w0rd

Comment: Was it ever good advice? To me the problem with the scheme that Randal proposed is, that it only has 44 bits of entropy. And that was many years after the 56 bits of DES had been brute forced. These days the bitcoin network brute force approximately 66 bits every 10 minutes.

Comment: @kasperd I think that because passwords are hashed multiple times (or should be) there is increased difficulty in finding a collision (or is it a preimage, I'm clearly not an expert)

Comment: @NickT: It's not clear what you're referring to, but generally speaking, multiple rounds of hashing *raises* the likelihood of collisions and *lowers* security. If you could hash an infinite number of times, you would always end up with the same hash regardless of the original password. The bcrypt algorithm is a little different because it reintroduces the original password or salt with each round.

Comment: Just for the record: If your password actually was `correcthorsebatterystaple` it now got a lot less secure!

Comment: @Aaronaught Every properly designed iterated password hash includes the password and salt in each iteration. That makes any increased probability of collisions a non-issue. The real drawback of iterated hashes is that they make the server an easier target for DoS attacks.

Comment: @NickT An iterated hash does make it harder to brute force the password. If you were to iterate 1000 times, that would give roughly the same additional security as 10 more bits of entropy. So the 44 bits of entropy in the password could quite possibly be as hard to crack as 56 bit DES or even harder. But even with the additional security from iterations, I don't consider 44 bits of entropy enough. I would recommend using a password, which is strong enough to not be broken, even if it is stored as a plain hash with no salt or iterations.

Comment: His method is better than what came before it: passw0rd123

Comment: @kasperd: You can recommend whatever you want; normal users don't care about bits of entropy and will only use a scheme that creates easy-to-remember passwords - or have them written down. The best of both worlds is a password safe, but even if you use one, there are some instances in which it's inaccessible. Aside from adding an additional word or two to an xkcd- or diceware-generated phrase, I'm not aware of any schemes that produce significantly more entropy without constantly leading to forgotten passwords.

Comment: I guess he forgot to calculate the loss of entropy when writing *“WTF”* instead of *“Watch This Fail”*. ;)

Comment: If you do use a password like `correcthorsebatterystaple`, take care that you aren't logging into a system that silently truncates it!  A password like `correcth` is probably easier to guess than `N#y;f8eR`.

Comment: @Leo I really think your comment needs to be elevated to an answer. The talk cites actual experts doing experiments and finding that the technique failed at its primary goal of making password more easy to remember. It furthermore says that people who had them made more mistakes typing them in due to the increased length. So while it may still be as secure as it ever was, it is not necessarily thought to be as good advice as it was before these studies. (I'd make the answer myself, but for some reason my 100 bonus points mean I'm trusted enough to comment but not to leave an answer.)

Comment: @trlkly: Hmm, same for me it seems. Need more reputation here to post an answer. Shame, was a good talk and took up a lot of points that are usually overlooked.

Comment: @Leo Fyi you have 101 rep from your account association bonus, more than enough to post an answer. Heck, commenting requires 50 rep and you're already doing that.

Comment: @Ajedi32: That's what I thought as well, but the fact remains that this site won't let me answer protected questions. My 100 points of association bonus do not seem to count when it comes to the 10 reputation points on this site needed to answer this question.

Comment: @Leo Really? That's weird. Looks like you're correct though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170937/192171

Comment: @snailboat Your comment about password truncation is an important one. It gets even worse, if a password is reused across different systems, which truncate at different lengths.

Comment: In practice, passphrases don't seem to help as much as XKCD would have you believe: [dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2335356.2335366](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2335356.2335366)

Comment: That's the reason why you buy the big dictionary instead of the small one. But can't you be creative? You could just think of a sentence like 'TheSloppyCthulhuAte10Sandviches". I just need to remember that. Once you know that you're misspelling Sandwich because of a populat videogame you like and you apparently can spell Cthulhu you're nicely set and done

Comment: [You can always use this to see password security](https://codepen.io/programmer5000/full/zZdaoJ/)

Comment: Why are all the answers so long? Simple answer is no, the guy is totally wrong in his reasoning, that attackers knowing the scheme makes it insecure. The XKCD comic does assume the scheme is known; it's all about entropy. And if the scheme isn't secure, it's not for the reasons he gave.

Answer (score 235):

## The Holy War

I think you will find that the correct way to generate passwords could start a holy war where each group thinks the other is making a very simple mathematical mistakes or missing the point. If you get 10 computer security professionals in a room and ask them how to come up with good passwords you will get 11 different answers.

## The Misunderstanding

One of the many reasons there is no consistent advice about passwords is it all comes down to an issue of *threat modeling*. What exactly are you trying to defend against?

For example: are you trying to protect against an attacker who is specifically targeting you and knows your system for generating passwords? Or are you just one of millions of users in some leaked database? Are you defending against GPU based password cracking or just a weak web server? Are you on a host infected with malware[1]?

I think you should assume the attacker knows your exact method of generating passwords and is just targeting you.[2] The xkcd comic assumes in both examples that all the details of the generation are known.

## The Math

The mathematics in the xkcd comic is correct, and it's not going to change.

For passwords I need to type and remember I use a [python script](https://github.com/redacted/XKCD-password-generator) that generates xkcd style passwords that are truly random. I have a dictionary of 2^11 (2048) common, easy to spell, English words. I could give the full source code and a copy of my list of words to an attacker, there are still going to be 2^44 possible passwords.

As the comic says:

> 1000 Guesses / Sec
> Plausible attack on a weak remote web service. Yes, cracking a stolen hash is faster, but it's not what the average user should worry about.

That strikes a nice balance between easy to remember and difficult to crack.

## [What if we tried more power](http://what-if.xkcd.com/13/)?

Sure 2^44 is ok, but GPU cracking is fast, and it's only going to get faster. [Hashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/) could crack a weak hash[3] of that size in a number of days, not years. Also, I have hundreds of passwords to remember. Even xkcd style it gets hard after a few.

This is where password managers come in, I like [KeePass](http://keepass.info) but there are many others that are basically the same. Then you can generate just one longer xkcd pass-phrase that you can memorize (say 10 words). Then you create a unique 128-bit truly random password for each account (hex or base 64 are good). 128-bits is going to be strong enough for a long time. If you want to be paranoid go larger, it's no extra work to generate 256-bit of hex passwords.

---

[1] This is where the memory thing comes in, if you're on a compromised host you have lost. It doesn't matter if you type it or use a program like KeePass to copy and paste it if an attacker can key-log / read memory.

[2] Rather than the weaker (but more likely) assumption that the attacker has just torrented a dictionary called "Top Passw0rdz 4realz 111!".

[3] Sure we should all be using PBKDF2, etc... but lots of sites are still on SHA1. (and they are the good ones)

Comment: I thought that GPU cracking is not possible because of memory constraints of the GPU. So if the dictionary does not fit GPU memory, then the only other option is to make a list of all possible passphrases, which is not possible for 5 word phrases and up.

Comment: @Dick99999 modern GPUs can have 6 GB of memory on a single card (although it would take 2 slots) and can easily store a dictionary of a few thousand words.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs This is scary and amazing in same time. My first (programmable) machine had 1mhz and 64kb ram and you talk about 6GB video memory...

Comment: @PTwr To be fair, i'm talking about an extreme high-end gaming card that costs a thousand euros and doesn't fit most standard computer cases. There's also an improved version that costs 3000 EUR and has 12 GB of memory, but also takes 3 slots.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs so... NSA have clusters of them? Even then, my phone have two thousands times more computing power and 8192 times more ram than my first computer. Oh the possibilities! And I just check emails on it...

Comment: I really like your password generator.

Comment: Is this sourced from somewhere? This all sounds very familiar.

Comment: "128-bit truly random password..." Truly random? Isn't it still pseudorandom?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if for no other reason than the Holy War part.

Comment: @DLeh You could always flip a coin 128 times and use that to generate and then enter a password into the storage tool manually.

Comment: @PTwr The NSA certainly uses vast amounts ASICs with fixed hardware that can do nothing but SHA1 (or MD5,..) in parallel. If you think a GPU is fast, just imagine something several orders of magnitudes faster with rather reasonable power consumption. Proof for how easy something like this is even for normal people are all those VLSI bitcoin miners out there. SHA1 with PBKDF2 is only a bandaid there, what you really want is something like scrypt that's designed to take lots of resources.

Comment: @user973810 Just for clarification I didn't write the generator, I just use it.

Comment: @DLeh I haven't looked that closely at KeePass's generation algorithm, your probably right about it being pseudorandom but you could just do `dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=16 | base64` and save that if you wanted truly random.

Comment: @TankorSmash I guess all creative work is derivative, it's my own answer but I got most of the ideas from somewhere else. For example the bit about 10 people and 11 answers I adapted from a Terry Pratchett book about Dwarfs, and probably wasn't originally for there.

Comment: @Hybrid It's the quote `where each group thinks the other is making a very simple mathematical mistakes or missing the point.` that must be from somewhere else

Comment: @TankorSmash Yeah, it's from http://blog.xkcd.com/2008/09/09/the-goddamn-airplane-on-the-goddamn-treadmill/ I just adapted "each group thinks the other is making a very simple physics mistake"

Comment: Or, even better than 10 random words, a meaningful phrase that's still hard to guess. For example, "`XKCD is a webcomic on the interwebz, and <http://explainxkcd.com/> has some 1337 explanations!`" (Just a random thing I thought of, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @Doorknob Once you choose meaningfull combinations most of the entropy dissapears. I won't try to estimate how many sentences you could pick, but this is probably closer to one in a billion than to one in 2^44.

Comment: Only 11 different answers? Not 12 or 20?

Comment: @JoeZ. 2^11, actually.

Comment: @JoeZ., who was it, (LBJ?) who upon hearing economists constantly saying, "one one hand... but on the other hand...", cried out, "Someone bring me a one-handed economist!"

Comment: The mathematics may be correct, but if users aren't careful, they can greatly weaken their password through a poor choice of words. For example, if they always choose 4 words **noun verb adjective noun** (to make an easily memorized sentence), that greatly reduces the number of possible solutions to try (brute force attack).

Comment: @DLeh: I'm sure he meant truly random vs a phrase, but KeePass does have plugins and built-in support for collecting additional entropy when generating the passwords, including getting the user to move the mouse arbitrarily or mash the keyboard.

Comment: @Doorknob "random thing I thought of" - that is a contradiction. Humans do not think of random things, in fact humans are very poor generators of entropy. The emphasis and assumption is that these are *actually* random, i.e. NOT something you "think of".

Comment: TL;DR use a password manager?

Comment: "The xkcd comic assumes in both examples that all the details of the generation are known." Well, sort of. The comic did briefly mention that "you can add a few more bits to account for the fact that this is only one of a few common formats".

Comment: _"I use a python script that generates XKCD style passwords"_  Don't forget that there is now a plethora of online XKCD style password generators.  Some also do this in-browser - like [xkcd.pw](https://xkcd.pw/).

Comment: "1000 Guesses / Sec Plausible attack on a weak remote web service. Yes, cracking a stolen hash is faster, but it's not what the average user should worry about." this may have been correct at the time of writing but these days I think cracking stolen hashes is a very valid worry - perhaps the most significant one?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin This is perhaps a rather late reply, but I think the rough figure is 1 bit of entropy per character of normal English, suggesting there are a billion 30-character English phrases.

Answer (score 164):

Schneier writes this:

> This is why the oft-cited XKCD scheme for generating passwords -- string together individual words like "correcthorsebatterystaple" -- is no longer good advice. The password crackers are on to this trick.

but the key to understanding what he is really after is a little further in his essay:

> There's still one scheme that works. Back in 2008, I [described](https://www.schneier.com/essays/archives/2008/11/passwords_are_not_br.html) the "Schneier scheme"

so that's it. Ole' Bruce wants to assert that *his* scheme is the One and Only, the best, the winner, the ultimate scheme. Therefore, he needs to say disparaging things about the "competitors", regardless of whether such assertions are scientifically sound or not.

In this case, it has *always been assumed* that the password generation method is known to the attacker. That's the whole point of entropy computations; see [the analysis](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase/6096#6096). That attackers are "on to this trick" changes *nothing at all* (when an attacker knows the password generation method, the entropy computation describes *exactly* the password strength; when the attacker is incompetent and does not know the password generation method, the password strength is only higher, by an amount which is nigh impossible to quantify).

The quip about "passwords in memory" is just more incoherent ramblings. Passwords necessarily go to RAM at some point, whether you type them or copy-paste them from a password safe, or anything similar.

My guess is that Bruce was drunk.

**Update** Schneier was specifically asked to comment about his passphrase condemnation in [a Reddit AMA](http://web.archive.org/web/20201029063805/https://www.reddit.com/r/security/comments/4vs90j/bruce_schneier_ama_live_here_from_13_pm_est/d61a4n5/?context=3) (via archive.org, [original link](https://www.reddit.com/r/security/comments/4vs90j/bruce_schneier_ama_live_here_from_13_pm_est/d61a4n5/?context=3)) that took place August 2, 2016.  He continued to advocate for his password creation system as a superior alternative to random word passphrases.  Schneier did say his scheme "gives you more entropy per memorizable character than other methods" which is true when compared to characters making up words. But this is also irrelevant when a system relies on memorizing words rather than characters, and you're allowed to combine enough words to generate adequate 'entropy' for your passphrase as a whole.

Comment: Yeah, I thought his comments were an odd departure from his typical good advice.  His recommended scheme probably isn't bad, but hasn't been subjected to much actual testing.  The passphrase approach is fairly easy to test in comparison, and you'd think that would appeal to the cryptographer in him.  Maybe he just skimmed over the news about cracking natural language passphrases and didn't see a distinction between those and random word passphrases.

Comment: None of the 'remarkable' examples form Schneier show any trace from being randomly chosen words. Furthermore  if these successful hacking exercises are given enough hash codes, they will find some phrases every week, nothing remarkable: it's in the math. Even if a 4 random word phrase requires 5 years of guessing on average, the chance that it will be recovered on day 1 is one out of 3650, see  see also <a href="http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60709/day-1-hit-chance-a-better-presentation-than-average-recovery-time-of-a-hashed-pa">my plea for day 1</a>.

Comment: Link to original Schneier post?

Comment: Your argument about him needing to denigrate the competition fails, since immediately after describing his scheme, he says "_Even better is to use random unmemorable alphanumeric passwords (with symbols, if the site will allow them), and a password manager like Password Safe to create and store them_".

Comment: @wfaulk Password Safe is Bruce Schneier's creation, so his argument about the competition still stands. Your fail statement fails ;-)

Comment: @AviD: I totally did not know that. 

Comment: @TomLeek, It's so easy to come up with a secure password scheme. Just roll a 62-side die X times and use the numbers that come up as your password.

Comment: I think what he was referring to was the fact that hash-cracking software has caught on to this trick. AFAIK they can now run rulesets that combine dictionary words and do 1337-text replacement and other very smart algorithms that would make this method much less effective. I would imagine all four words from the XKCD comic would be in a dictionary list. It wouldn't be all that long before they combined and an iteration of the letter replacement rules found out which ones had been altered. Game over. Against the standard "combine all the letters" brute-force method it would work well.

Comment: What you're missing, and apparently Schneier as well, is that there is no "trick" to "catch on to". The security of Diceware *already assumes the attacker knows about the scheme*, in fact it assumes the dictionary itself is known. It doesn't matter if the attacker has your exact dictionary and number of words: there are simply too many combinations to go through to make any sort of successful attack before the sun explodes.

Answer (score 99):

[Disclosure: I work for AgileBits, the makers of 1Password]

One of the reasons why I advocated for an XKCD-like scheme (before it got called that) in [Toward Better Master Passwords](http://blog.agilebits.com/2011/06/21/toward-better-master-passwords/) back in 2011 is precisely because its strength does not rely on the attacker knowing what scheme you used. If I may quote myself

> The great thing about Diceware is that we know exactly how secure it
> is even assuming that the attacker knows the system used. The security
> comes from the genuine randomness of rolling the dice.  Using four or
> five words should be sufficient against the plausible attacks over the
> next few years [given observed speed of password crackers](http://blog.agilebits.com/2013/04/16/1password-hashcat-strong-master-passwords/) [against
> 1Password Master Password]

What the XKCD comic does not effectively communicate is that **the selection of words must be (uniformly) random**. If you ask humans to pick words at random, you get a heavy bias for concrete nouns. Such biases can and will be exploited.

### How much strength you want

In a perfect world we would want to strength of our password to be as strong as the keys we are protecting with it. Say 128 bits. But despite these techniques, humans aren't going to achieve that. So let's look realistically at attacks and what we can have our puny little brains do.

With the original Diceware word list of 7776 entries, you get approximately 12.9 bits per word that you use. So if you want at least 64 bits for your password, then five words will do it.

#### Guessing passwords is slower than guessing keys

In this section I arrive at a very rough back of the envelope estimate that for a constant amount of dollars it is 2^13 times slower to test a password than it is to test an AES key.

Note that testing a password is a lot slower than testing a key. If the right sorts of password hashing schemes are used, it is possible to keep most attackers down to under 100000 guesses per second. So while we might never want to use 50 bit keys, using 50 bit passwords might still make sense.

If we aren't going to limit ourselves to rolling dice as in Arnold Reinhold's [original Diceware scheme](http://world.std.com/%7Ereinhold/diceware.html) from 1995, then we can use a longer list of words. The Strong Password Generator in 1Password for Windows uses a list of 17679 English words between 4 and 8 letters inclusive (stripped of taboo words and words that involve an apostrophe or hyphens). This gives about 14 bits per word. So four of these gives you 56 bits, five gives you 70.

Again, you do need to pay attention to cracking speeds. [Deep Crack](https://w2.eff.org/Privacy/Crypto/Crypto_misc/DESCracker/HTML/19980716_eff_des_faq.html#howsitwork) back in 1997 was able to run 92 billion DES tests per second. Assuming that a high end specialized PC can perform one million guesses per second against a reasonably well hashed password could do 1 million guesses per second, then passwords today are about 16 bits harder to crack than DES keys were in 1997.

So let's look at [this Stack Exchange estimate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22905/how-long-would-it-take-a-single-processor-with-the-aes-ni-instruction-set-to-bru) for a dual core 3.8GHz processor: 670 million keys per second. If we were to assume $5000 in hardware, we can easily exceed 10 billion keys per second. So at a similar hardware cost, key cracking is still more than 2^13 times faster than password cracking.

#### Revised password strength goals

Working on my estimate that it is 2^13 times more expensive to test a well-hashed password than it is to test an AES key, we should consider a reasonably well hashed password as being 13 bits stronger than its actual entropy with respect to cracking. If we want to achieve 90 bits of "effective strength" then 77 bits of password strength should do it. That is achieved with a six word Diceware password (77.5-bits) from the original list and 84.6 bits with six words drawn from a list of 17679 words.

I don't expect most people to use passwords that long. I expect people will use things that are 4 or 5 words long. but if you are genuinely worried about the NSA going after your passwords, then six words should be sufficient assuming that you use a decent password hashing scheme.

#### Very rough estimates only

I didn't spend a lot of time researching costs and benchmarks. There are lots of things in my estimates to quibble with. I attempted to be conservative (pessimistic about the scheme I'm advocating). I've been vague about "well-hashed passwords" as well. Again, I'm being very conservative with respect to the password hashing in 1Password. (For our new data format, attackers have been kept to under 20,000 guesses per second and for our older data format they've reached 300,000 guesses per second for multi-GPU machines. In my estimates here, I've picked 1 million guesses per second for a "reasonably well-hashed password".)

### A few more historical notes

The overall idea for "XKCD-like" passwords goes at least as far back as the [S/Key one time passwords](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1760) from the early 1980s. These used a list of 2048 one through four letter words. A six word S/Key password got you 66 bits. I don't know if this idea of using randomly selected words from a list for a passphrase predates S/Key.

In 1995, Arnold Reinhold proposed [Diceware](http://world.std.com/%7Ereinhold/diceware.html). I don't know whether he was aware of S/Key at the time. Diceware was proposed in the context of developing pass phrases for PGP. It was also before most computers had cryptographically appropriate random number generators. So it actually involves rolling dice. (Although I trust the CSPRNGs on the machines that I use, I still enjoy "rolling up a new password").

In June 2011, I revived interest in Diceware in [Toward Better Master Passwords](http://blog.agilebits.com/2011/06/21/toward-better-master-passwords/) with some additional modification. This resulted in my 15 minutes of fame. After the XKCD comic came out, I produced a [geek edition](http://blog.agilebits.com/2011/08/10/better-master-passwords-the-geek-edition/) that walked through some of the math.

In July 2011, Randall Monroe had picked up on Diceware-like schemes and published his now [famous comic](http://xkcd.com/936/). As I am not the inventor of the idea, I don't at all mind being upstaged by the comic. Indeed, as I said in my [follow-up article](http://blog.agilebits.com/2011/08/10/better-master-passwords-the-geek-edition/)

> What took me nearly 2000 words to say in non-technical terms, Randall
> Monroe was able to sum up in a comic. This just shows the power of math ...

But there is one thing about how the comic has been interpreted that does worry me. It is clear to me and people who already understood the scheme that the words must be chosen through a reliably uniform random process. *Picking words "at random" out of your head is **not** a reliably uniform process*.

Comment: Great that you mention Diceware in a historic perspective and at the same time acknowledge the great marketing job XKCD did for passphrases. About your modified scheme, is anywhere explained why 3 or 2 letter words are not included in those word lists? see http://blog.agilebits.com/2013/04/16/1password-hashcat-strong-master-passwords/expanded-dicelists/ . Is it because the words like 'off' and 'line' could also be attacked by 1 word offline?  See my comments on the post of Raestloz. The original Diceware list contains many 1, 2 and 3 letter words.

Comment: Excellent question!

My (possibly erroneous) thinking at the time was that I also wanted passphrases to be a minimum length. I wanted to make sure that if someone used a three word passphrase, it would exceed a minimum of 12 characters in length.

I note that S/Key also allows 1, 2, and 3 letter words.

Comment: I quickly checked the word lists my SimThrow passphrase generator and tester uses. The original Diceware list has at least 1400 of these collisions like 'any' 'how' and 'anyhow'. That may degrade a 4 word sentence to 3 words, if no separator is used. It's a high collision number because that list includes all letters and 2 letter combinations. So it seems you made the right choice to not include 2 letter words. Diceware advises a minimum sentence length of 17. My generator estimates both the word and character based recovery times, to cope with sites that allow short passwords (20) only.

Comment: I also checked the following wordlists. [S/Key](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1760.html): > 93 collisions, [expanded-dicelists US](http://blog.agilebits.com/2013/04/16/1password-hashcat-strong-master-passwords/expanded-dicelists/): > 190  and my Netherlands list: >  750. A way to handle this is to recommend including a separator character between the words of a phrase.

Comment: Beware, rolling dice is not perfectly random.  http://www.forbes.com/sites/davidewalt/2012/09/06/dice-chessex-gamescience-roll-randomn/  And http://www.insidescience.org/blog/2012/09/12/dice-rolls-are-not-completely-random

Comment: Best way to use Diceware is to use a prefix free wordlist. The original diceware wordlist wasn't prefix free, but EFF had created an [EFF English wordlist](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2016/07/new-wordlists-random-passphrases) that is prefix free.

Comment: In developing the word list that we now use in the 1Password generate, I looked at making it prefix-free. but it really cost to many words.

There is a much simpler solution. Insist/encourage use of separators between the words.

Comment: cool answer I even took the fun and extracted the Wordlist 1pw uses from the mac application (simple enough with 7zip) and wrote a little PHP script which I can run locally to generate words, which is really nice especially considering that list is a LOT longer than diceware. but what I'd sometimes like is when creating phrases for others here in germany would be a decent wordlist for diceware or anything as the diceway list for that has WAY too much junk in it that arent even words, or anything

Answer (score 62):

The XKCD password scheme is as good as it ever was.  The security doesn't derive from it being unknown, but from it being a good way to generate memorable passwords from a large search space.  If you select the words to use rather than generate them randomly, though, this advantage is lost -- humans aren't good at being random.

The bit about memory is poorly stated, but it *is* a concern: if password-stealing malware ever gets on your computer, it'll sweep up everything text-like from RAM and the hard drive to use in a directed attack on your accounts.

Comment: +1 I don't think the XKCD technique is dead - it's not 'a trick' that crackers 'are on to'. You can know the technique inside out but that doesn't make it any more crackable if it's random enough.

Comment: @PiTheNumber if you're using not enough words or a tiny dictionary, then you aren't applying the xkcd technique at all; but no, even in the xkcd comic it's explicitly clear that you are ***NOT*** losing your advantage if you tell everyone "hey, I'm using correcthorsebatterystaple style password" - the amount of veriations/entropy bits is higher than most normal passwords even if the method is known.

Comment: Provided you don't also use XKCD's random number generator (I won't link, everyone knows it).

Comment: @PiTheNumber the concept of '11 letter truly random password' is irrelevant, as it is not a reasonable alternative to passphrases. Passphrases are alternative to *memorizable* passwords, and those are exactly as weak as xkcd describes.  Sure, if you use a password stored in a password manager, then completely random passwords fit, but in that case it's essentially not 'your password' as in something that *you* would use or see, but rather an 'autogenerated random key token' similar to ssh keys.

Comment: @PiTheNumber The words are not human-chosen, they are chosen randomly. The dictionary from which the words are chosen is itself human-chosen, but that is a different matter. There is no “most likely” — the math in the xkcd comic is correct.

Comment: @SteveJessop, you mean my password "droiddroiddroiddroid" isn't a good one? :(

Comment: @PiTheNumber Yes, that's the whole point of the XKCD comic: it gives a method to have a computer-generated password that's both more secure than a mostly-human-generated password (more entropy) and easier to memorize. And Jeff completely misunderstood the whole thing (his remark on “cutting the entropy” is total bullshit).

Answer (score 16):

As others have said, the attack Bruce Schneier describes is effective when the user chooses multiple words him/her-self, not using a tool.  Schneier usually writes to a general public audience, which is unlikely to grasp the difference between self-chosen "random" words and program-chosen random words.

I'll add that even if you use a script or other tool to randomly choose words from a dictionary, **you have to use the first sequence it gives you**.  If you decide, "I don't like that one," and run it again until you do like it, *it is no longer a random passphrase*, it is human-chosen.

Also, even if you use a script, and even if you don't damage the randomness by choosing your favorite of multiple sequences, there is still the possibility that an attacker could exploit your PRNG (pseudo-random number generator).  If the attacker can learn when you created the password, and what PRNG you used, and maybe other information about your PRNG such as network traffic that was produced using your PRNG around the same time, that could reduce the effective entropy of your random passphrase.

Perhaps a bit esoteric, but if your PRNG is exploitable, the 2^44 figure will not be fully realized.  (And if you assume "no one will try to exploit my PRNG", why do you care about using a truly secure passphrase?)

Comment: +1 Interesting angle. Exploiting the PRNG is obvious in the context of encryption keys - it's interesting that it seems to be virtually an afterthought here. I guess typical passwords are so bad that PRNGs feel secure by comparison. Presumably, if an attacker can steal a list of hashed passwords, finding the pwdChangedTime or equivalent would be trivial? Another reason to end the practice of password aging?

Comment: Quick back of the envelope. If you update the password within a minute of generating it and the only source of entropy in your PRNG is the system time, you may be looking at cutting things down as far as 2^35 for nanosecond resolution. Sound reasonable?

Comment: Suppose I reject a phrase because I don't like a word and do that 1000 times. Then I have reduced the dictionary by 1000 words. Is the choice from that reduced dictionary still random? If it still is, then a 4 word sentence from a thus reduced 7776 word Diceware dictionary still gives (7776-1000)^4 = 2.1E15/50.9  possibilities/entropy bits, down from 3.7E15/51.7 possibilities/entropy bits for the full dictionary. I am not able to judge the influence of the random generator. I use the one from www.random.org

Comment: @imsotiredicantsleep I don't know that much about how PRNG attacks are done, but my sense is that they are most successful when analyzing how they are *initialized*.  The Mersenne Twister has a period of 2^19937 - 1, so previous outputs don't help the attacker much.  But if you know it was seeded with (for example) current timestamp, MAC address and CPU serial number, and you know what day a password was created, that might be a lot easier.

Comment: @Dick99999 I don't think it's really about the number of offered choices you exclude in choosing one password.  It's about the *pattern* of what phrases you *would* exclude, if presented to you.  An attacker might guess that the user will prefer shorter words, words easier to type on a QWERTY keyboard, and words with no capitals or punctuation; this strategy could greatly shrink the space of passphrases to explore.  Basically, it's the same issue as just guessing favorite sports teams, birthdays and kids' names.

Comment: @wberry I don't think the math works out on that. Suppose you reject 1000 passphrases before finding one you like. Then it's a reasonable estimate that you only like 1/1000 of the possible password space. Now suppose that an attacker is able to completely guess which 1/1000 of the space is your favorite - that reduces the number of possibilities from 2^44 to 2^34, which is significant but not so much that an extra word can't pad out the loss. Plus, if you limit your rejections even this is not necessary.

Comment: A quick way to roughly estimate the strength of a "random passphrase with rejections" is to start with the nominal strength in bits (assuming no rejections) and subtract one bit for considering rejections at all. Then, while generating passphrases, subtract another bit every time the number of rejections hits a power of 2 (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.). Or just subtract 10 bits and assume you'll give up long before rejecting 512 random passphrases. (Of course, that assumes you always restart from scratch after rejecting a phrase, rather than rejecting individual words as you generate one phrase.)

Answer (score 11):

**It depends.** One thing you need to understand is that this is not security-by-obscurity: **the entropy values used in the comic assume that the attacker already knows you're using this method**. If the attacker doesn't know how you're generating the passphrase, then the entropy goes up massively.

The trick to the XKCD method is that you need to actually use a random number generator and a good word list: **never pick the words yourself, not even "randomly"** (in quotes because humans are actually really bad at picking things randomly, which is why you shouldn't do it). [Diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) has tools to help you do this, and even takes the random element out of the computer's reach by using ordinary dice.

Against a broad-based attack -the sort of thing where an attacker got a list of passwords from a Website and doesn't know anything about whose passwords are in the list- this is as strong as it ever was. Just as you say, its strength comes from the power of exponents (and a good word list).

Schneier's attack can work, but only in an entirely different context. **His attack assumes that you are being specifically targeted, by an attacker who already knows a great deal about you**. This might not seem especially worrisome at first, because the stereotypical determined attacker is an intelligence agent behind a screen, and most of us don't have to worry so much about those: there are only so many of them, and each one can only afford to care about so many people. But it's actually more of a problem than it might first seem, thanks to the advent of sophisticated malware. A malware installation can afford to care about you even though the attacker does not, and so you still wind up facing an extremely determined attacker. Even more determined than a human could be, in fact, though far less creative.

Malware that compiles information on you will give words that seem important to you very high priority in the word list. It does this because most people pick the "random" words themselves, but in so doing, they actually bias quite strongly toward the words that are most important to them: it may still "feel" random, but some words are much more likely to come up than others. For that reason, giving these words high priority often results in relatively quick hits, and this is the "trick" that Schneier is talking about.

**However, you can still thwart Schneier's attack by using real randomness**. The catch is that this requires discipline: all decisions about what words to use in your passphrase (aside from choosing a good word list) must be taken completely out of your hands. This is where things like Diceware can help you.

Comment: Your first paragraph is almost completely wrong (which is a pity, because your answer is otherwise good). The fact that the attacker knows that you're using the xkcd method does not significantly reduce the entropy. What would reduce the entropy is if the attacker knew which words you would pick — which he won't, if you follow the xkcd method, because you are supposed to pick them at random (not mentally, but with a die or something similarly truly random).

Comment: @Gilles: The reason that the entropy goes down if the attacker knows the method is that it changes the whole structure of the password. If you don't know the method, then "correct horse battery staple" looks like 216 symbols from a 2-symbol alphabet: in other words, 216 bits. If you know that it's four English words (and know XKCD's wordlist), then it looks like 4 symbols from a 2048-symbol alphabet. 2048^4 is big, but it's smaller than 2^216, which is how many bytes of entropy a truly random bit string of that length would have. But XKCD's claim already accounts for that: 2048^4 = 2^44.

Comment: Assuming that attackers believe that passwords are bit strings that follow a uniform distribution is a totally unrealistic model of attackers. Knowing the method only accounts for a handful of bits of entropy.

Comment: Then why does XKCD claim that a 27-character string only has 44 bits of entropy?

Comment: Entropy is not defined on strings, but on methods to generate strings. XKCD describes a method to generate strings, which has 44 bits of entropy. The domain of that method contains strings that are 27 characters long, as well as strings of other length — but the length of the strings isn't interesting from a security perspective, only from a usability perspective.

Comment: Then it sounds like my error was only a matter of terminology. I was speaking about the entropy that a password of a known length appears to have. If you know nothing about a password other than its length, then a 27-character string appears to have 2^216 bits of entropy. If you know that it's four random English words, picked from a 2048-word list and separated by spaces, then it appears to only have 2^44 bits of entropy (i.e. what XKCD claims). If you know (or can correctly guess) other models, then the apparent entropy changes accordingly. I will edit the answer to state this.

Comment: Why would you know the length of the password, but not the fact that English words are more likely than average to appear in passwords? Again, your attacker model is completely unrealistic. Attackers don't go “hey, I'll generate all possible 27-letter passwords”. They go more like “hey, I'll generate all possible passwords in decreasing order of likelihood”.

Comment: @Giles [Actually both the string and method are relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Relation_to_entropy). You claim The Spooniest's opening paragraph is wrong, while making an argument that seems to restate it. If you don't know how the password is generated the entropy does go up greatly - ~166 bits for 27 characters (upper, lower, digit, punctuation). What you are saying is that attackers can use knowledge of how passwords are generated to reduce this. Seems like you are arguing the same thing from opposite ends. Also, not knowing the length *increases* the entropy.

Comment: @imsoredicantsleep: Exactly.

Comment: @Giles Suppose the attacker knows that it's a 4 word passphrase without seperators. Suppose the dictionary used is NOT known, instead a 100.000 word dictionary is used. That generates  1E20/66 possibilities/entropy bits, up from 8.1E13/46 possibilities/entropy bits for a 3000 word dictionary. The entropy goes up quite a bit.

Comment: @Giles 67 bits of entropy, not 66: you have to round up to account for the extra fraction (even though it's less than 0.5). That's nothing to sneeze at, but still a far cry from 216. I'm also not sure that you could get a good wordlist that long out of English, because a good wordlist has to be picky about things like substrings. Might make an interesting programming challenge, though.

Comment: @Spooniest: If you're talking about communication bandwidth and ideal compression, round that fractional bit up.  If you're talking about password strength, round it down.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Point taken. Best-case versus worst-case. My mistake.

Comment: I'd argue that even to a sophisticated attacker who doesn't know that the XKCD method was used, a passphrase like `correcthorsebatterystaple` still doesn't have much more than 44 bits of entropy. One empirical argument for this is the fact that the [zxcvbn password strength estimator](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html) puts it at about 49 bits (10^14.4 guesses ≈ 2^48 guesses ≈ 49 bits). Funnily enough you could also argue the comic indirectly anticipates this ("You can add a few more bits to account for the fact that this is only one of a few common formats.").

Answer (score 5):

The strength math is quite simple if word choice is at random: (number of words in dictionary)^(number of word in the sentence), assuming the attacker knows the number of in the dictionary. So a 5 word phrase using a known (**by the attacker**!) 7776 word Diceware dictionary: has 7776^5=2.8E19 or 64 bits of entropy.

There is one item that is not mentioned in the scheme: by adding just 1 (random) character at a random place in the whole phrase, the strength is up by about 10 bits, see [Diceware, Optional stuff](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html).

The above math also does not account for separator symbol between the words. That can add another 5 bits.

Comment: The point (or at least one of them) of the XKCD comic is that adding one random character at a random place increases the difficulty of memorizing the password more than it increases the difficulty of cracking it.

Comment: True for memorizing in general, not true for a master password of a vault, I think. I see 'easy to type' as the main advantage. I encounter more and more situations where password managers cannot fill in the  password (apps, WifI guest network) and I have to type them.

Comment: @Mark - the extra random (or just non-dictionary) characters could be the same across all your passwords meaning you won't forget it. You'll earn the extra bits of entropy at least until several other of your passwords are compromised at which point the password is still xkcd-strength...

Comment: @imsotiredicantsleep - That is a very interesting suggestion. Always looked for a solution to make this strengthening technique more easy to use. It could be called security by obscurity because the attacker can benefit from the knowledge about the random character and the position. A slight trade off, I think between ease of use and secure.

Comment: @Dick99999 absolutely, it's a trade off. But until the constant component is compromised it will defeat a naïve dictionary attack, and significantly slow a more sophisticated one. I don't agree that it's security by obscurity though, as I can tell you that I am using the *technique* without losing the entropy that the *possible  values* give me. The main weakness is that once the constant part is known you have *sacrificed password real-estate* that could have been randomised.

Comment: @imsotiredicantsleep, agree I was wrong about the security by obscurity part. The scheme is very similar to one I promote for password managers: for really sensitive passwords like bank accounts, use one (the same) 3-6 character pre- or postfix for all accounts. It is only memorized. I add it manually to the part that is stored in the manager when opening the account.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also like to add a **yes** answer also, but for other reasons. It's not a good advice [in general] because of length constraints:

- Sites like Skype, ING, eBay, and in my country Binckbank ans KPN limit passwords to 20 characters. (That bank limit is 15, but it used 2 factor authorization)
- With an average length of 4.5 characters/word for a short 3000-8000 word dictionary, that allows for using 3-4 word phrases only.
- When using large dictionaries the average may be 6-7: 3 words only
- If the site insists on using a symbol and a number in the password, only 18 characters are available for the phrase.

Those lengths only protect against online attacks. For Off-line attacks is depends on the key derivation and hash function, iteration counts and cracking hardware used by the site of app, whether a 3-4 word phrase offers sufficient protection.

Comment: Sites that limit the length of passwords are often a great indicator that their password storage system is very insecure. Run away. All in all, password strength requirements tend to be more detriminal than helpful, IMO (both to security and memorability).

Comment: Add Suntrust to the list of passwords limited to 15 characters. I wonder what is up with that industry..

Comment: I can tell you what is up with that industry: during testing, someone somewhere some time ago screwed up something that caused long passwords to fail. Probably they made the database column too small. The bank decided it was cheaper to just limit the field. Other banks saw it and, knowing that banks make profitable decisions, copied it. *Most* users never complain about not being able to have a longer password, so it was never in their (apparent) financial interest to change.

Comment: On the flip side, it's significantly easier to type 'correcthorsebatterystaple' on a smartphone than keep toggling between lowercase, uppercase, numbers and punctuation.

Comment: Microsoft accounts must not have more than 16 characters (they also impose a minimum of 8).

Comment: Low password limits don't just mean insecure password storage methods--they mean passwords are being stored in plaintext or are encrypted (not hashed).

@Ángel My passwords for all Microsoft-related accounts are longer than that, so I call BS.  Ages ago, before NTLM, Windows passwords were limited to 16 characters, iirc.  That predates XP and is hardly relevant.

Comment: @Zenexer Regarding the Microsoft accounts: Microsoft online accounts (live.com, Office 365, etc.) are limited to 16 characters (letters, numbers and some symbols are allowed).

Comment: "It's not a good advice [in general] **to have** length constraints" (There, fixed it.)

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think so.

The actual advice in that xkcd comic are to **use mnemonics that are easy for you to remember** and **generate password as long as you can remember them**. Those are basic password advice anywhere, and will always stand true (even the quoted Schneier's method uses these two basic facts). Indeed, the comic makes use of common English words, but your implementation doesn't have to be, nor did the comic implies that you should.

Of course, the most secure passwords are totally random strings like how an MD5 string looks, and you probably can use a password manager to store all those passwords, but then **what password are you going to use for that manager?** ¯\ *(ツ)* /¯

Comment: "Of course, the most secure passwords are totally random strings" NO, see for a comparison  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Random_passwords

Comment: Wouldn't diceware also generate a bunch of words combined into one? Which is the one Schneider tried to crack?

Comment: Like: off line -> offline? In that case the attacker would have to use a much larger dictionary. The average length of words in a Diceware compatible dictionary is to short to have these kind of 'duplicates' within the dictionary, but I will check this. But your point is a good reason to include a separator character between the words like a space(?) or a dash.

Comment: No, that's not what the xkcd advises, I suggest you read it again - and the analysis in the relevant question here (linked above).

Comment: I answered a comment and question on Diceware not on an xkcd advise. How else can you interpret "a bunch of words combined into one"

Comment: Your signature "¯\ (ツ) /¯" is an excellent password: short, easy to remember, really hard to break, hard to detect as a password on a log.

Comment: @Daniel Azuelos, ... trivial to add to a list of strings in common usage...

Comment: @imsotiredicantsleep everything is trivial enough to add to a list of common usage. Even random string like supermanEyjafjalgladoslajökullbatman can also be added to a list of common usage if the attacker knows about it beforehand.

Comment: @Raestloz, but that string **isn't** in common usage. The signature is - it's an emoticon like the smiley face. Google returns 121,000 results for a copy & pasted version of the signature, probably many more if I could be bothered to type it properly. And it returns zero results for your string. Common vs (apparently) unique.

Comment: I do not think that string is common enough in passwords usage (which is what the attacker would be interested in). But anyway, is a katakana even a valid password character? I thought passwords exclusively only accept ASCII?

Comment: @Raestloz A person speaking a language that doesn't use characters that lie in the ASCII range isn't going to use an ASCII password. Do you think all those people in Asian lands use two keyboards, one for everyday typing, and one for passwords? Unlike thirty-year-old operating systems, like DOS, all modern OS's handle Unicode and other character sets/pages just fine, and any website should support them (so long as the developer doesn't encode the form using a random charset each time, or let the browser choose). Passwords are just bits that mean something to humans.

Comment: @phyrfox No, it's quite common to use passwords in the ASCII range in Asia.  Besides which, Japanese and Chinese input methods defeat input masking, showing each character as you type it.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to have the right context.  The [xkcd comic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase) compares `Tr0ub4dor&3` at an assumed 28 bit entropy (though I [calculate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93611/password-rules-should-i-disallow-leetspeak-dictionary-passwords-like-xkcds-t/93628#93628) it as 34.6) to `correcthorsebatterystaple` and its assumed 44 bits of entropy (a four word [diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) code is 51.7 bits … but one of those words isn't diceware. Using a simple 100k-word spelling dictionary, I calculate it to be 66.4 bits).

First, let's make this easier to understand.  There are 94 printable characters.  A one character password has `log₂(94) = 6.55` bits of entropy.  Two characters have `log₂(94²) = 13.10` bits of entropy.  You can divide the final entropy of a password scheme by 6.55 in order to determine the equivalent complexity of a purely random password as measured in characters.

Therefore:

- 28 bits of entropy ≈ 4.3 character password (very bad!)
- 44 bits of entropy ≈ 6.7 character password (also bad)
- 66.4 bits of entropy ≈ 10.1 character password (okay for 2016)

Trusting xkcd's numbers, you can see why Schneier was concerned.  This seems a bit overblown, as most attackers will still give up after ten or so characters <sup>[citation needed]</sup> —it should take a few years for a big cluster to break a 10-char MD5 hashed password— though obviously if a good attacker knows your scheme, absolute character length isn't an issue.

**The total complexity of the scheme is most important.**  You must assume the worst case (that the attacker knows your exact scheme).  It's a great idea to additionally ensure your password is 11+ characters ([when permitted](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33470/what-technical-reasons-are-there-to-have-low-maximum-password-lengths)), but that's a secondary priority (and it comes for free with pass phrases).

### Create pass phrases with four words plus a passcode

Here is my passpharse creation advice (with entropy estimates):

- Make a nonsensical "sentence" of 4+ words of 4+ characters each (100,000⁴)
- None of these words can be connected to you –or each other– *in any way*
- Use case, spaces, and at least two symbols or punctuation marks (32²)
- At least one word should fail spell check (e.g. leetspeak, foreign words, 64 each)
- Include at least one other "error" (spelling/grammar/syntax, entropy unknown)
- Between two words, add a traditional "random" 7+ char passcode (92⁷)

This should be at least `log₂(100000⁴ × 32 × 3 × 64 × 92⁵) = 112` bits of entropy (which is very strong, ≈17 chars). I skipped capitalization (I assume only the first char is uppercase) and one symbol (I assume it ends in `.`, `!`, or `?`, so the second symbol has a complexity of 3) and I also assumed that "random" isn't quite random and calculated the code as a five character equivalent (strict adherence to the above formula would give you 128+ bits of entropy at ≈20 chars).

That final point is worth repeating:

### Humans are very bad at generating randomness

Very very few human-generated "random" character passcodes even *approach* true randomness.  There will be patterns in the code related to the person's keyboard, favorite numbers, and/or an assumption that a certain obscure word is unguessable.

I designed this scheme to be robust against people's inherent lack of randomness; assuming a limited vocabulary (say the 2600 words in [Basic English](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Basic_English_combined_wordlist)), use of related words (penalized by counting only three words), and a passcode limited to just the entropy of six alphanumerics, `log₂(2600³ × 62⁶)` itself is still strong at 70 bits (≈10.6 characters).

*Don't let this water down your passphrase!*  This section is present to demonstrate that this scheme has some resistance to the limited entropy of human choices, not to encourage poor choices.

The only real trouble comes from people who take quotes or lyrics as their four words.  These pass phrases are trivially defeated if the quote or lyric can be guessed (say by looking at your Facebook likes) or would otherwise have an entropy of around 6 random characters at a crack time of 30 seconds (MD5) to 17 days (PBKDF2).

You can use [my entropy table](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93611/password-rules-should-i-disallow-leetspeak-dictionary-passwords-like-xkcds-t/93628#93628) to calculate the entropy of your passphrase scheme.

<sub>(Don't concern yourself with the fact that [passwords briefly live in memory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/are-passwords-stored-in-memory-safe) unless you're a developer)</sub>

Comment: It should also be noted that non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters are like silver bullets, defeating most attacks automatically.  A password of `•••••••••` (nine bullet characters) is embarrassingly secure (and looks the same masked as unmasked!) due to length and obscurity, though it'd be a _horrible_ idea to actually depend on just this fact.  Put a non-ASCII character in your passcode+4word and your complexity skyrockets (to calculate, use its unicode value), though perhaps **at the expense of portability** (what if you're using a friend's smartphone?)