# Should I run my password through Bcrypt before using it for encrypting a file with AES-256?

Tags: cryptography, aes, file-encryption, bcrypt, key-stretching

I need to encrypt a file with a password that can be memorized. So I was thinking about running the password through some rounds of Bcrypt before using it for AES encryption, so every time I want to encrypt/decrypt I want it to take about 10 seconds in my machine (meaning brute-forcing it wouldn't be possible).

What I want to ask you is whether doing this is 0K, since normally one shouldn't mess around with cryptography. Doesn't AES have this already built-in? I mean configurable number of rounds or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security of bcrypt/sha256 key used with AES to encrypt a file](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/29481/20074).

Answer (score 1):

There are many gotchas in the overall approach so I'll pick a narrow path.

First off, AES does NOT have any such thing in-built. It just takes a key and does it's job. There are no artificial "work factors" built into it.

Secondly, folks rarely "brute force" the password - they use dictionary based attacks along with a long list of permutation rules to try out "likely" password.

For your purpose, you can use either bcrypt, scrypt or pbkdf2 to slow down dictionary attacks. I would still recommend using longer pass phrases and also `salt`ing the keyboard password before it enters bcrypt/script or pbkdf2.

You should know that between you entering the "in-your-mind" password on your keyboard and the AES crypto library getting the real AES key, there can be many potential areas of weakness. eg: If you copy-paste the bcrypt output (=AES key?) into some other program (encryption program?), it's on your clipboard for ANY program to snoop on.

Comment: Why would I add a salt? Doesn't bcrypt already do that?

Comment: Yes, bcrypt can accept a salt value in it's input but you still have to actually provide/store it. Basically don't pass null or zeros taking any short cuts. You might not but just saying ....