# Recommended options for LUKS (cryptsetup)

Tags: aes, luks

I'm looking for recommended options for cryptsetup to create fully encrypted SSD (`SanDisk SSD U100 128GB`), which achive:

```
Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 1476 MB in  3.00 seconds = 491.81 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 1420 MB in  3.00 seconds = 473.01 MB/sec
```

My benchmark shows me best cipher:

```
# cryptsetup benchmark
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
PBKDF2-sha1       103696 iterations per second
PBKDF2-sha256      59904 iterations per second
PBKDF2-sha512      38235 iterations per second
PBKDF2-ripemd160   85111 iterations per second
PBKDF2-whirlpool   47216 iterations per second
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-cbc   128b   133.2 MiB/s   432.0 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   128b    18.1 MiB/s    67.3 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   128b    39.3 MiB/s    73.0 MiB/s
     aes-cbc   256b    99.6 MiB/s   337.7 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   256b    18.1 MiB/s    66.9 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   256b    39.4 MiB/s    72.6 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b   376.6 MiB/s   375.0 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   256b    69.0 MiB/s    66.5 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   256b    71.1 MiB/s    72.2 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b   297.0 MiB/s   300.1 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   512b    69.6 MiB/s    66.6 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   512b    71.9 MiB/s    72.7 MiB/s
```

But perhaps, you could suggest some options, that would increase my performance and security. My CPU is: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2677M CPU @ 1.80GHz` and it supports AES-NI (`aes` cpu flag).

Thank you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You might want to use PBKDF2 with SHA-512. This step is for converting your *password* into an encryption key (more or less directly). This is inherently open to [offline dictionary attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack), and relates to the [password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) problematic. For that, you want to maximize the effort of the attacker by choosing an algorithm and iteration count which will make the task hardest for the attacker while keeping it tolerable for you; "tolerable" here depends on your patience, when you type the password at boot time.

Attackers will want to use some [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) and/or [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) to speed up their attack, while you use a normal PC. Nowadays, normal PC are at ease with 64-bit arithmetic operations, and run SHA-512 about as fast as SHA-256; however, GPU much prefer 32-bit operations, and mapping them on FPGA is also easier than 64-bit operations. Therefore, by using SHA-512 instead of SHA-256, you give less an advantage to the attacker. Hence my recommendation: on modern hardware, for password hashing, prefer SHA-512 over SHA-256.

Remember to adjust the "iteration count" so that the time taken to process your password is at the threshold of the bearable: higher iteration counts mean longer processing time, but are proportionally better for security.

---

For actual encryption, you will want [XTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEX-TCB-CTS#XEX-based_tweaked-codebook_mode_with_ciphertext_stealing_.28XTS.29), which has been designed to support disk encryption efficiently. This indeed shows in the benchmarks; this is for a SSD and you do not want the encryption to be much slower than the underlying hardware. Note that XTS splits the key into two halves, only one of which being used for the actual encryption. In other words, "`aes-xts`" with a 256-bit key actually uses 128 bits for the AES part. And that's [good enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6141/amount-of-simple-operations-that-is-safely-out-of-reach-for-all-humanity/6149#6149). There is no rational need for going to 256-bit keys -- i.e. 512-bit in the context of "`aes-xts`". 256-bit keys for AES imply some CPU overhead, which the benchmarks duly observe (300 MB/s vs 375 MB/s). With a SSD under the hood, you really want a fast encryption system, so do that.

Comment: Thank you.  I've been looking for an answer like yours.  *"Note that XTS splits the key into two halves, only one of which being used for the actual encryption. In other words, "aes-xts" with a 256-bit key actually uses 128 bits for the AES part."* -> Do you know any reference either in code or documentation that shows that it is the exactly what LUKS implements?  I just really need to have it verified.  Or is there a way where I could "visibly" be able to demonstrate this? (luksDump doesn't do much help.) Should I look for and rely on verbosity configurations in kernel?

Comment: @konsolebox See: [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Encryption_options_for_LUKS_mode), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory#XEX-based_tweaked-codebook_mode_with_ciphertext_stealing_.28XTS.29).

Comment: I am a bit confused about `There is no rational need for going to 256-bit keys`.  Does it mean when using `cryptsetup` to encrypt, specifying `--key-size=128` is enough that `--key-size=256` is unnecessary?

Comment: So, the key sizes shown by `cryptsetup benchmark` for `aes-xts`, are they the sizes given on the command line, or the halves of them, that are actually used?

Answer (score 7):

Any combination of the above operation modes will provide you with ample security against most threats. That said, `CBC` is no longer recommended due to certain information leakage attacks. And `SHA1` is depreciated in favour of the `SHA2` family.

As always with crypto, stick with what is widely used and proven. So my overall recommendation would be: `PBKDF2-sha256 aes-xts`

Comment: Seconded, with a 256 bit AES key - 512 is overkill

Comment: @Michael, even if I'm a next Snowden? :)

Comment: @ArturSzymczak - if you are Mr.Snowden, you already know all this and more.

Comment: @Artur, yes, even then. A 256 bit AES key is no where near the weakest link in your security setup.

Comment: System performance is important. If you can have 26% better performance with an equivalent security level, it's probably a good idea. There have also been [suggestions that AES-256 (used with a 512-byte XTS key) has weaknesses in the key schedule compared to AES-128](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html).