# Designing a cryptographic file-sharing protocol

Tags: cryptography, aes, file-encryption, rsa

As a learning project, I am trying to implement a secure way to share files with a friend over dropbox. (I am not looking for existing software, I am doing this in order to learn how to do this right.)

Of course I will not try to invent my own encryption algorithm.

I have a file that I want to send to my friend securely.
We both have my Project-to-be on our machines, and a shared dropbox folder. (although means of transfer should be irrelevant).

Each of us has a RSA keypair, we have exchanged public keys using a secure method (in person via USB stick, or via GPGed email).

I will use

> RSACryptoServiceProvider with a keysize of 4096 bits

for these Keys.
(I am considering maybe soon 8192 bits, since I found out that the huge pause of 8-11 seconds in my test application isn't caused by RSA keypair generation, nor encryption, but by `key2string` or `key2base64` operations!)

The Keys are stored locally in a text file. The private key is encrypted with

> AESCryptoServiceProvider in CBC mode, PKCS7 Padding, 256-Bit.

The IV will be completely random generated by the CSP.
The symmetric key will be derived from a password using

> Rfc2898DeriveBytes (==PBKDF2), 1000 Iterations, salt from RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

(Salt length == final key length)

The file is encrypted, again using

> AESCryptoServiceProvider in CBC mode, PKCS7 Padding, 256-Bit.

Key and IV will be completely random for each file, produced by the CSP itself.

The IV will be prepended to the encrypted filedata.
This package will be hashed using

> HMACSHA512 with a random key.

I don't know whether to use `RNGCSP` or the HMAC internal `randomkeygen`, because until now,
I wasn't able to find out how secure that internal method is. (Is this NIST-approved?)

The HMAC will be prepended to the IV:cryptedfile package.

The HMAC-Key and the AES-Key will be (separately) encrypted with my friend's public key, and in such encrypted form be prepended to the package:

> cryptedAESKey:cryptedHMACKey:HMAC:IV:cryptedfile

this package will be saved as binary to the shared DropBox folder, using the same name and extension the original had.
This is because I haven't worked anything out for the filename yet, not even thought about it, suggestions are very welcome.

On the receiving end, of course the process works in reverse:

1. enter passphrase to unlock private key
2. decrypt HMAC and AES Key
3. authenticate file
4. decrypt using key and iv
5. save as original filename

---

So, am I doing it right?
In other words, do you see any problems, any faux-pas, no-gos, misunderstandings on my side, whatever? I am looking for your experienced verdict on my project, what could be done better, different, not at all, additionally? I think I covered all the things in [lessons learned](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology) and everything my research has brought to surface.

Right now, I am not interested in hiding the existence of communication. Furthermore, the keyhandling inside my application is also not of interest right now, I will get into that as a next step (securing memory against dumping etc.) after I've got the crypto part right.

Comment: bcrypt bcrypt bcrypt bcrypt bcrypt

Comment: Aerovistae: bcrypt is for password hashing/key derivation, not encryption. And in any case PBKDF2 (which he is using for key derivation) is perfectly fine.

Comment: You may find the [cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) site useful.

Comment: A university professor in Math once told me, "doing cryptography right is not doing it yourself".

He meant you always make a mistake, and crypto works as a LOT of mathematicians, crypto-analysts and security researchers have checked the work.

Great to try if you are learning though.

Comment: Are you a cryptographer working to earn your degree in crypto? Have you read any books about common crypto protocol errors? If not, then you really shouldn't be attempting this... it's just way too hard to get right, and literally multiple books have been written on what goes wrong. It's waaaaay too broad for stack exchange

Comment: no, I am not a cryptographer, but a very paraoid and very interested individual. unfortunatelly my original post has been heavily censored by some mod (I think) - originaly there was some background information. also: why do I have to be a cryptographer for wanting to implement cryptography? and further... in your eyes, how does one become a cryptographer, so far I haven't found any cryptography bachelor or master teaching me how to implement sth, only theoretical mathematics.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Making your own crypto is fine as long as you understand that it is for *learning*, not for *using*.

There are several "layers" in cryptography. There are *algorithms*, like RSA, AES, SHA-256... Then there are *protocols*, which assemble algorithms together. And then, there are *implementations*, which turn protocols into executable code. For a first grasp of cryptography, I usually recommend to go to implementation first: get an existing protocol, and implement it. This has some nice benefits, including the possibility to test your implementation against others, which is great in tracking bugs. This will also give you some insights on how protocols are structured, e.g. to support streamed operation.

Since you are concentrating on the sending of a file as a single message, the model appears to be close to what [OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) purports to solve; therefore, making a working implementation of OpenPGP in C# is what I recommend.

**If you still choose to make your own protocol right away**, then the following can be said about your choices:

- Your key sizes are overkill. 256-bit AES keys are quite useless in practice, since 128-bit keys are already quite far beyond that which is breakable with existing technology (e.g. see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6141/amount-of-simple-operations-that-is-safely-out-of-reach-for-all-humanity/6149#6149)). Similarly, 4096-bit RSA keys are oversized; 2048 bits are already more than enough to ensure security. Since larger keys imply reduced performance, oversized keys imply unrealistic slowness which will not be representative of what can be achieved, thus lowering the pedagogical value of the whole endeavour.
- Conversely, 1000 rounds of PBKDF2 could be considered as too small. For a password-to-key conversion, the iterations are there for a "muscle show", to cope with the inherent weakness of the password (that is, the inherent weakness of the meat bag who will have to remember it), so you want that iteration count to be as high as is tolerable, thus relating to the power of your computer and your patience. A typical count value, with today's computer, would be around 100000 or even some millions.
- You use a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) for the encryption of the file, but not for the encryption of your private key. This looks strange. There *are* situations where a MAC is not necessary, but most contexts where encryption is warranted also call for a MAC. It would be simpler to use the same format for both encryptions.
- You apply the MAC on the encrypted file: that's [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac), and that's good -- and you *did* think of making the encryption IV part of the MAC input, which is even better (that's a classic mistake which you neatly avoided). You might want, though, to make some allowance for some future *algorithm agility*: maybe, at some point, you will want to use another symmetric encryption algorithm. In that case, some symbolic identifier for the encryption algorithm should also be part of the MAC input; this can be as simple as a first byte of value 0x00, leaving you some root for 255 other future algorithms.
- You use HMAC with SHA-512, which is not bad, but SHA-256 is not bad either and will offer substantially better performance on 32-bit systems. There again, race to the largest outputs and key sizes is artificial and sterile. SHA-256 is more than "secure enough".
- CBC mode and a separate MAC are "old style". There are modern encryption modes which combine the encryption and the MAC within a single primitive, reducing the possible scope of implementation errors; in particular, [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) and [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). I understand that .NET does not offer them (yet); [`CipherMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx) is limited to CBC, CFB, CTS, ECB and OFB. In that case, CBC is not the worst choice, with an extra MAC (i.e. HMAC, as you suggest). To use CBC properly, an unpredictable random IV is necessary, and that's what you suggest (good).
- Be extra wary when implementing the decryption. You should first verify the MAC, and then, only if the MAC verification succeeded, may you proceed with the decryption. The tricky point is in the padding handling: an attacker could try to extract secrets from the recipient, by sending altered files and see how the recipient reacts, e.g. when the recipient found a syntactically valid padding or not. This is the basis of [padding oracle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack). You can process the incoming data in blocks, computing both the MAC and the putative decryption in parallel, but take care, for the last block, to compute and check the MAC first (this is the kind of hurdle that is avoided with GCM or EAX).
- Encrypting the key for AES and the key for HMAC is weird; it would allow a creative attacker to swap them around, making the recipient use the HMAC key for decryption, and vice versa. Although the benefits would not be obvious, it is very hard to tell whether a vulnerability exists that way; it depends on how "different" AES is from HMAC, a property which is not well-defined and, in any case, has not been thoroughly investigated.

  It seems safer, and also more performant, to use a single "master key" *K*, encrypted with the recipient's public key, and to derive the AES key and the HMAC key from it with some [Key Derivation Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). It can be as simple as making *K* a 256-bit key (generated randomly) and splitting it in two halves, one for AES and the other for HMAC. Or you could make *K* longer (or even shorter), hash it with SHA-256, use split the SHA-256 output into two halves. The point is that a single RSA encryption is needed, not two. Also, deriving the encryption and MAC keys from a single source will map better to a possible future use of GCM or EAX.
- Your file format does not allow for streamed processing. In your format, the MAC is computed over the complete encrypted file, but its value comes first, *before* the encryption result. This means that the sender will have to process the whole file before beginning the sending. Thus, for a 1 GB file, 1 GB of temporary disk space (or RAM) will be necessary. This could be avoided if the MAC value was appended at the end, rather than stored in a prefix.

  Note that this buffering issue necessarily exists for the recipient, who must verify the MAC before using the decrypted data in any way. To fully cope with that, you would have to make a more complex format, with moderate-sized chunks, each with its own encryption and MAC, and some glue for secure assembly. The model would be [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) here.
- There is no authentication ! The recipient has no way of knowing whether the file he received indeed came from the alleged sender. To add authentication, in your setup, you will need [digital signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). Note that a digital signature may replace a MAC, *if applied adequately*, which is not an easily guaranteed property. It is safer to simply compute a signature (with the *sender's* private key) over the complete structure.
- There is no protection against [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack). An attacker, observing a file in transit, could send the same file again at a later date. It is then up to the recipient to take measures to detect such duplicates. This can be as simple as a date somewhere within the data file, under the protection of the MAC (and possibly the encryption, although this is not necessary), but it must be given some thought.
- By encrypting the private key yourself, I understand that you do not let the operating system take care of it. This could be limitative. Indeed, a [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) instance could, potentially, use a key which physically resides in a [smart card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card); and even for software keys, there can be some security benefits with letting the OS take care of the storage (the OS has privileged access to the hardware, and can, for instance, avoid leaking secret keys to the disk through [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)). By using an explicit key *file*, you make your system incompatible with such potentialities, which is a shame.
- There is no room for metadata, in particular a *content type*. The same sequence of bytes can have several interpretations, and there can be amusing consequences if the recipient can be induced into opening a HTML file as PDF or vice versa. Ideally, that which you actually encrypt should be a structure with a header containing a designation of the type of data (e.g. a [media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)) followed by the data itself.

All of this is said in no particular order and without claiming exhaustivity. The synthetic conclusion is that protocol design is not simple; it helps to have some solid implementation experience on which to base the design.

Comment: thank you for your very good answer, I will carefully look at each of your suggestions and read some further material. About the overkill: I'm a paranoid guy, so please excuse. I clearly see the fault with the PBKDF iterations, don't know why I put 1000 there... I'm thinking of using a number to gain a 1 second delay on my machine now, like KeePass offers.

Comment: accepted this as answer since it was the best one, and this question is already forgotten, so it is unlikely any new ones will come in. thanks!

Comment: SHA-512 is faster on 64-bit systems

Answer (score 0):

You should try implementing with some newer block ciphers, for example Threefish with 1024 bits. Also try using a combination of 3 or more block ciphers which would protect against an algorithm break in one of them. Look into how Truecrypt uses a combination of AES, Twofish and Serpent together. Perhaps use an algorithm from each of the 3 main superpowers. One from Russia, one from China and one from the US.

Potentially think about encrypting the MAC as well, see the UMAC specification. Think about using one of the NIST hash function competition finalists. With Skein you could have a 1024 bit HMAC.

Assuming your potential adversary has a quantum computer now or in the near future, your 128 bit encryption would be reduced to 64 bit using Grover's algorithm. A 256 bit hash would be reduced to 128 bit with a brute force search.

This post will be downvoted/deleted/censored by a moderator shortly.

Comment: "This post will be downvoted/deleted/censored by a moderator shortly." I saw that and I didn't even bother reading your post and instead decided to downvote it regardless of potential merit.